# Javascript with input validation

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I want to change this code:

```
            $(document).on('change', '.full_w form .body input.beschrijving:last', function(event) {
                $('.full_w form .body').append('<input id="a" class="beschrijving" style="width: 430px"  type="text" name="beschrijving[]" /> <input style="width: 54px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" /> <input style="width: 94px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" /> <input style="width: 18px" type="text" maxlength="" name="btwp[]" /><br /><br />');
            });
        });
```

To something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.full_w form .body input.beschrijving:last', function(event) {
                $('.full_w form .body').append('<input id="a" class="beschrijving" style="width: 430px"  type="text" name="beschrijving[]" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Voer een beschrijving toe')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"/> <input style="width: 54px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" pattern="\d+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Vul een aantal in')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" /> <input style="width: 94px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Voer een prijs in van uw product')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"  /> <input style="width: 18px" type="text" maxlength="" name="btwp[]" pattern="\d+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Vul een btw bedrag in 0 tot 100')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" /><br /><br />');
            });
        });
```

I can't get this worked so i hope someone can help me with this

EDIT

This line need to change:
From:

```
.append('<input id="a" class="beschrijving" style="width: 430px"  type="text" name="beschrijving[]" />
```

To this

```
.append('<input id="a" class="beschrijving" style="width: 430px"  type="text" name="beschrijving[]" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Voer een beschrijving toe')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"/>
```

Comment: Could you put a brief text description of the change you want? The major part of the code, which by necessity is on one line, is hard to read.

Comment: Firstly, you haven't escaped your quotation marks, there is a ' inside a " inside a ' which will break. Secondly, write the code as part of functions in a script tag and then call them from the onvalids

Comment: Don't put the input validation like that. Implement a real solution like http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: I Tried to fix that but i can't get the code accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey mate i am not sure that it will work or not but try with this

```
$(document).on('change', '.full_w form .body input.beschrijving:last', function(event) {
    $('.full_w form .body').append('<input id="a" class="beschrijving" style="width: 430px"  type="text" name="beschrijving[]" oninvalid="setCustomValidity(\"Voer een beschrijving toe\")" onchange="try{setCustomValidity(/"/")}catch(e){}"/> <input style="width: 54px" type="text" maxlength="" name="aantal[]" pattern="\d+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity(/"Vul een aantal in/")" onchange="try{setCustomValidity(/"/")}catch(e){}" /> <input style="width: 94px" type="text" maxlength="" name="prijs[]" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?" oninvalid="setCustomValidity(/"Voer een prijs in van uw product/")" onchange="try{setCustomValidity(/"/")}catch(e){}"  /> <input style="width: 18px" type="text" maxlength="" name="btwp[]" pattern="\d+" oninvalid="setCustomValidity(/"Vul een btw bedrag in 0 tot 100/")" onchange="try{setCustomValidity(/"/")}catch(e){}" /><br /><br />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with quotes , backslash `'` in your functions calls , Try this :

```
.append('<input id="a" class="beschrijving" style="width: 430px"  type="text" name="beschrijving[]" oninvalid="setCustomValidity(\"Voer een beschrijving toe\")" onchange="try{setCustomValidity(\"\")}catch(e){}"/> ');
```

Answer (score 0):

ahhh If I understood correctly you want to append an element and also add a few events to it. You should do it something like this: (there are many ways to do it, this is just one)

```
.append($('<input/>').on('change',function(){ /* do something */ })
                     .on('valid', function(){ /* do something else */ }));
```

Hope this helps